# Speed up ":not" jQuery CSS selector in IE 8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, internet-explorer, jquery-selectors

I am having trouble with performance in IE and I am doing a large loop that has this selector:

```
td:not(.some-cell)
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this in IE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE8 does not support `:not` selector natively, so if you are using pure-script selectors engine like Sizzle built-in to jQuery, it may be performance issue due to slow pure-script search through all elements.

Most simple solution is to mark each that `TD` element with a specific class on server side, and then select them just with class selector.

```
<td class="not-some-cell"></td>

<script>
    // instead of $('TD:not(.some-cell)')
    var myCell = $('TD.not-some-cell');
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you know this but :not() is a built in CSS selector. I'm just telling you. I just wasn't sure if you knew that.

Comment: IE older than 9 does not support it.

Comment: Do you mean IE younger than 9?

Comment: IE8 is older than IE9. This is established terminology.