# Why jQuery filter script is slow in IE, but quick in Chrome,Firefox,Opera

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

[Dutch page containing `DIV` blocks which can be hidden using a jQuery script.](http://www.staplijst.be/linken-van-en-naar-staplijst.htm)

If you look at this page with **IE** , you will notice that the filtering (hiding/unhiding `DIV` blocks is **very slow**.

**I am using IE 8, Opera 11, Firefox 11, Chrome 18.**

Using any other browser: **Chrome**, **Firefox** and **Opera**, it's **much quicker**.

- Can any bode tells me why this is ?
- Or can anyone make a suggestion to make it more responsive in IE ?

This is the snippet I use to perform the filtering :

```
<form class="searchBox">
   Zoek naar <input type="text" name="filterargument" id="filterargument" />
   <input type="button" name='filterbutton' id='filterbutton' value="filter..." />
   <i>(deel van de) clubnaam , de federatie of het clubnr</i>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
   var $filterArgument =  $("#filterargument");

   $('#filterargument').keyup( function() { performFilter(); });
   $('#filterbutton').click( function() { performFilter(); });

   function performFilter() {
      var filterArgument = $filterArgument.val();

      if (filterArgument === '') {
         $('.filterbaar').show(); }
      else {
         $('.filterbaar:not(:icontains("' + filterArgument + '"))').hide();
         $('.filterbaar:icontains("' + filterArgument + '")').show();
      }
   }
</script>
</div>
```

Comment: Hint #1: it affects IE 8 and below but not IE 9. Hint #2: it is related to `:not`.

Comment: What version of IE you are using?

Comment: Likely related to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9950813/speed-up-not-jquery-css-selector-in-ie-8

Comment: @pst Agreed - I'd start by trying to rewrite those "else" selectors

Comment: I have edited my question to include the version numbers of the browsers I am using.

Comment: @pst The other question you put there is just saying that `:not` is better not used, but I don't want to go back to the server and use another class. The whole point is that the filter should occur without reloading the page.

Comment: @mikevoermans Any sugguestions ? There is not much to rewrite here. I know I should better not use `:not` , but how else I going to hide the elements which are not selected by the filter ?

Comment: @Edelcom It was just to say *why* it was slow, not necessarily to provide an answer (and why it was linked to, not marked as a duplicate). It's easy to generate non-ideal selectors for jQuery/Sizzle and has nothing to do with reloading the page (or not).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have any version of IE to test, but let me know if this performs better:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

 var $filterArgument =  $("#filterargument");

 $('#filterargument').keyup( function() { performFilter(); });
 $('#filterbutton').click( function() { performFilter(); });

    function performFilter() {

        var searchFor = $filterArgument.val();

        $('.filterbaar').each( function() {
            var text = $(this).text();
            regex = new RegExp(filterArgument,"gi");

            if ( text.match(regex) ) {
                $(this).show(); 
            } else {
                $(this).hide();
            }

        });
    }


});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks very much. This indeed solves the problem. Even IE8 now performs adequately. Just had to correct some small errors (replace a , with a ; and used the filterArgument variable in stead of the searchFor you used. But after this changes, it works. I will put the changes to the page online this morning (I always develop locally at the PC, so you wont see the change immediatly online should you visit the page in my question immediatly). Thanks again, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put: IE JavaScript performance is pretty poor.  It is improved in IE9, however still comparably slower than the browsers you mentioned.  http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-performance-rundown/

That said, there are some improvements you can make to your JavaScript to help IE out: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2006/08/28/728654.aspx

Comment: This is not necessarily true. In any case, the issue is *likely* not even related to the JavaScript (from the JS engine viewpoint there is not much in the above that *can* be slow) but rather the DOM.